# with salt how to access reclass vs pillar data?

Tags: python, yaml, salt-stack, configuration-management

Im looking at the readme on the salt-swift  [formula](https://github.com/openstack/salt-formula-swift), and this has me wondering:

```
  rings:
    - name: default
      partition_power: 9
      replicas: 3
      hours: 1
      region: 1
      devices:
        - address: ${_param:storage_node01_address}
          device: vdb
        - address: ${_param:storage_node02_address}
          device: vdc
        - address: ${_param:storage_node03_address}
          device: vdd
```

Where are the variables: `${_param:storage_node01_address}`  to be defined? 
this is the pillar, i would assume the addresses would simply be placed in right here.

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely just put the addresses right there. You could also define pillar data in the regular manner and access it from there.